# Metodo de login que recebe os dados do usuario

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, login

Estou fazendo um projeto e tentando criar um método para login simples

Tenho a seguinte Classe **Usuario**

```
 public class Usuario
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Senha { get; set; }
        public bool Admin { get; set; }
    }
```

E o seguinte **método de login**

**Metodo Get**

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {

            return View("login");
        }
```

**Metodo post**

```
  [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(string login, string senha)
    {
        ViewBag.login = db.Usuario.Where(x => x.Login.Contains(login) && x.Senha.Contains(senha)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (ViewBag.login != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {

            return View("login");
        }
    }
```

Minha duvida é, ele faz o login corretamente, vendo se o login e a senha digitadas conferem com a do banco, mas, também gostaria de saber se consigo carregar a informação da coluna admin juntamente com o login e senha para que posteriormente eu use essa informação em uma view por exemplo

**Exemplo: usuário1, senha 123, admin: false**

Se eu logasse normalmente com usuario1 e 123 ele puxasse o false do admin junto

Answer (score 1):

Felipe, antes de mais nada, eu não aconselho você usar o método "contains()" para testar login e senha. Isso porque o método contains vai buscar na sua base de dados qualquer usuário que possua tais caracteres e não o usuário com exatamente as mesmas credenciais digitadas. O ideal nesse caso é utilizar o método **equals**.

Troque isso:

```
ViewBag.login = db.Usuario.Where(x => x.Login.Contains(login) && x.Senha.Contains(senha)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Por isso:

```
ViewBag.login = db.Usuario.Where(x => x.Login.Equals(login) && x.Senha.Equals(senha)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Sobre a sua dúvida, precisaria entender um pouco melhor. Você já está puxando esses dados do banco? Existe uma tabela "Usuario". Ou é um usuário fixo que você está usando através da classe usuário?

Pergunto isso pois aparentemente você já está pegando a coluna admin nessa linha:

```
ViewBag.login = db.Usuario.Where(x => x.Login.Contains(login) && x.Senha.Contains(senha)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Basta você acessar na view dessa forma:

```
@ViewBag.login.Admin
```

Comment: Não seria uma boa prática incluir todo o usuário no ViewBag.
Escolher algo tipo de informação séria mais interessante, como:
ViewBag.Email = usuario.Email;
Ou coisa do tipo

Comment: Ótima observação, Edvaldo. Para passar o objeto inteiro ele pode utilizar a view fortemente tipada. Seria melhor.